# Is it possible in Dynamics CRM 2011 to find what permission is lacking when it shows access denied

Tags: exception, dynamics-crm-2011, security-roles

Is it possible in Dynamics CRM 2011 to find what permission is lacking when it shows access denied?

For example a logged on user is trying to create a new Account through the Regarding field on an Email Activity. When she hits the new button she is shown

```
Access Is Denied 
You do not have enough privelleges to access the Microsoft Dynamic CRM object or perform the requested opertaion...
```

I would like to list at the bottom of this message what permission CRM thought it needed (I only need to have this function during testing and would turn it off in production). Or if that's too hard I would love to know the location of a log that tells me what permission was required along with the username so I can tweak the security matrix appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to enable developer errors. Instead of getting the standard Crm error message you get a more complete message, complete with stack trace. This will then you give the missing privilege name.

Described [here](http://rostacik.net/2011/07/07/how-to-turn-on-developer-errors-in-microsoft-crm-2011-aka-titan-or-5-0/).

Also as Jason explained usually you get a privilege name you can make sense of, but in the case you don't check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334308.aspx).

Security Role UI to Privilege Mapping - Will show you which privilege name is linked to which selection on the Ui.

The other pages will help if Crm ever returns you a Guid instead of a privilege name.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with Jason's approach - though mine is a little quicker in this case, in other situations you may need actual tracing (which can only be enabled via making a registry change - there are tools on the net to help you with this).

Comment: I agree that his is an excellent answer, but yours answered my question which was how to show a full diagnostic on the error page. I upvoted both because I think both approaches have merit and I can see circumstances where you might prefer one over the other.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to figure it out if you enable tracing on the CRM server. It isn't going to tell you explicitly which permission is missing but should give you a pretty good idea, you'll see exception messages like "missing PrvReadAccount privilege", meaning the user is missing Read permissions on the Account entity.

[How to enable tracing in Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907490)